# two pointers same reference

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm really new to C++, I just learned it a couple of weeks ago. I have a problem with 2 pointers individually pointing to the same reference. When I try to reassign *workingOn then *user turns into garbage.

Here is the code:

```
    std::cout << static_cast<int> (user->getPermission()) << endl; // return 0

Customer  c_temp(username, password, Permission::CUSTOMER);
s_customer.push_back(c_temp);
workingOn = &s_customer[s_customer.size() - 1];
std::cout << static_cast<int> (user->getPermission()) << endl; // return random memory

return customerLoggedInScreen();
```

get Permission is an enum that can either return 0,1,2 which include manager, customer, maintenance.

*user can either be a manager or customer
*workingOn is the person you're working on. Which could be yourself (as the customer)

The code could of been designed better... but I wasn't too comfortable with polymorphism and C++

I'm trying to change the person the user is workingOn but afterwards my pointer turns into garbage memory. Initially the user and the person working on are the same.

Here is the initialization of the user:

```
void Controller::login()
{
bool loggedIN = false;

using namespace std;
string input_password, input_username;

//call the login screen

    UI.login(input_username, input_password);


    /*
    If the user is not a customer we will login as a manager
    */
    for (int i = 0; i < s_customer.size(); ++i) {
        user = &s_customer[i];

        if (user->getUsername().compare(input_username) == 0 && user->getPassword().compare(input_password) == 0) {
            user_loggedIn = input_username; // store the person who is logged in

            if (user->getPermission() == Permission::CUSTOMER) {
                workingOn= &s_customer[i];
                return whatUItoDisplay();
            }
            return whatUItoDisplay();
        }
    }
```

}

in my header I have:
public:
    std::vector  s_customer; // This will hold all the customers in the program

```
Interface UI;
std::string user_loggedIn;
Customer *user = nullptr;
Customer *workingOn = nullptr;
```

Comment: _std::cout_ doesn't returns anything useful *by design*.

Your code sample is too much cut of details, hard to undrestand what's going on, thus a problem to suggest you anything useful.
Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Well basically permission is an enum that can return 0,1,2. s_customer is a vector array, and workingOn and user are both Customer pointers.

Comment: _I_ can possibly guess what you intended to do. No one can say the same about others.
If you'd like to receive useful answer, please adjust your question.
Not in comments, but editing and formatting original question.
The community will help to adjust it as required later, but at the moment it's far from being obvious to understand your question

Comment: Can we see the initialization of `user`?

Comment: I added the initialization hopefully that helps.

Comment: It seems like `user` is pointing into the vector, but later on you `push_back` onto the vector . (This renders `user` invalid since the vector contents may move in memory).

Comment: To avoid this sort of error, avoid using raw pointers. Instead you could store an integer index .

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are getting garbage values since `user` is no longer valid if the vector `s_container` is resized. When you call `s_container.push_back( ... )` and there isn't enough capacity, internally the vector will call `realloc( )` which has a chance (very likely) to change the memory location to the next available contiguous block of memory to fit the new capacity.

Check out this [table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector#Iterator_invalidation) covering when iterators (or any references to memory for that matter) are invalidated in vectors.

[image: Invalidation Table]

There are a few things you can do to resolve this. The first option is to store an index to the user rather than the pointer itself. This ensures the memory is valid since it's just an offset from the correct memory location.

```
user->
```

becomes

```
s_container[ userIndex ].
```

Another option is to use a container that guarantees pointer/iterator validity after adding elements. The most common one in the STL is [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque). Here's the [invalidation table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque#Iterator_invalidation) for deques.